# convert bit array values into a string of binary numbers

Tags: java, arrays, binary, type-conversion

**Just look at lower part now**

I've seen on here before ways to convert hex to binary, but my question is: is it possible to convert hex values inside of a byte array into binary values and put it into a big string?

The code I've been working on so far is:

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    byte [] ex;
    ex = new byte [] {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0x11, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0x22, (byte)0xDD, (byte)0x33, (byte)0xCC, (byte)0x44};
    printByteArray(ex);

}

public static void printByteArray(byte [] array)


{
    System.out.print("[  ");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(Integer.toHexString((array[i]>>4)&0x0F).toUpperCase());
        System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(array[i]&0x0F).toUpperCase() + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println( "]");
}
```

What I want is to change is to be able to put the whole binary string into a byte array, i.e., to get the binary values for each hex number and then put it all into on HUGE byte array.

**EDITED**

Okay well I'm going with the first one it doesn't matter all that much I guess how long they are, they were still correct. But now could you just help me take and use that string. I have this code :

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    String binary;
    byte [] ex;
    ex = new byte [] {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0x11, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0x22, (byte)0xDD, (byte)0x33, (byte)0xCC, (byte)0x44};
    printByteArray(ex);
    binary = hexToBin(ex);
    System.out.println(binary);

}

public static String hexToBin(byte [] array)
{
    String binStr = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        binStr.append(Integer.toBinaryString(array[i]));
    }
    return binStr;
}
```

... but due to the fact of how I initialized the string (at first) my output has `null` in it. Any ideas how to fix that? Also I just changed it to append and now I don't know why but won't let me use it?

Comment: These are two different questions.  You should separate them as such.  In other words, "follow-up" questions should be their own question.

Answer (score 1):

Would Integer.toBinaryString give you what you want?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)

```
public static void printByteArray(byte [] array)
{
    System.out.print("[  ");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(array[i]));
    }
    System.out.println( "]");
}
```

Comment: close, but do you know how come there would be a ton of 1's printed out, like i was expecting 64 1's or 0's but there is probable twice that

Answer (score 1):

Try this (note that `byte` is 8 bit not 16 as you seem to suggest above, which may be part of the confusion, for 16 bits you would want a `short` and 32 would be `int`)

```
public class PrintBytes {

  public static void printByteArray(byte [] array)

  {
    System.out.print("[ ");
    for (byte anArray : array) {
      byte b = anArray;
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        System.out.print((b & 128) < 1 ? "0" : "1");
        b <<= 1;
      }
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println( "]");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printByteArray(new byte[] {64, 32, -1});
  }
}
```